# Bundle Workflow fails consistently if the Bundle has large number of Items

Tags: workflow, bundles

I am using the standard out the box workflow definition “Task Process”. When I add more than 13 items exact to the Bundle, it always fails at the 14th every single time. The error message in the Event log was:

> The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error
>   processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the
>   remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket
>   timeout was '00:01:00'. The write operation failed, see inner
>   exception. The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by
>   an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded
>   by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local
>   socket timeout was '00:01:00'. An existing connection was forcibly
>   closed by the remote host
>
> Component: Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService
>
> Errorcode: 0 User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
>
> StackTrace Information Details:    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
>   size, SocketFlags socketFlags)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer,
>   Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer,
>   Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedConnection.WriteNow(Byte[]
>   buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, BufferManager
>   bufferManager)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer,
>   Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream.Write(Byte[] buffer,
>   Int32 offset, Int32 count)    at
>   System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.StartWriting(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.ProcessWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.ProcessWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 count)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer,
>   Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer,
>   Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer,
>   Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout,
>   BufferManager bufferManager)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.FramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnSendCore(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportDuplexSessionChannel.OnSend(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.OutputChannel.Send(Message message,
>   TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransactionDuplexChannelGeneric`1.Send(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContextBase.Reply(Message message,
>   TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.Reply(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)

I tried to increase the WCF `maxReceivedMessageSize` and `receiveTimeout` properties for the main Tridion Web.config files with no luck

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You increased the maxReceivedMessageSize but the error is about a timeout, not about the data received. You may have to change the Timeout settings instead - anyway, do open a support ticket, this doesn't sound right.

Comment: Thanks Nuno, you are right, the timeout I found in the config files is 10 mins, and the error is saying 1 min , and I read that this message could be misleading, and the size would be the problem specially, the Components I am adding to the bundle are super sized components.

Comment: OK, I'll try to take a look - I saw timeouts before, but after 200+ components, and also using the default of 1 minute.

Comment: Is this when you _add_ an item or when you _start_ the workflow?

Comment: it happens when finishing the last activity of the workflow. Thanks Nuno for looking into it

Comment: Quickly tested, no issues with 60 components in a bundle, OOTB workflow. The workflow agent uses the configuration in [Tridion]\bin\TcmWorkflowAgent.exe.config, which is set by default to 10 minutes, so it's not the workflow agent. Is there any error logged in the Windows Event Viewer?

Comment: Thanks Nuno, I could not fit the error in this comment window, what way you like me to send you the error

Comment: I just Added the detailed error message as part of the question Text

Comment: Are there any automatic activity (is your WFAgent service running ?)
BTW your UI(or WFAgent) tries to connect to CoreService, which is running in context of the TcmServiceHost (I mean, that if you want to change timeout property you must change it in TcmServiceHost.cfg, not web.cfg).

Comment: I have also faced the socket time out error. But in my case I was trying to create core service client using netTcpBinding. But using basic HTTP it was working fine for me. I too need the answer why I faced this issue when I uses netTcpBinding for connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for everyone commented, and tried to help to resolve my issue, Finally the issue was resolved by help from SDL Support, and here are the steps taken to resolve the issue:

```
1. In Tridion\bin\TcmServiceHost.exe.config
-  Change the CoreService_netTcpBinding binding
<binding name="CoreService_netTcpBinding"
transactionFlow="true"
transactionProtocol="WSAtomicTransaction11"
maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
closeTimeout="00:30:00"
openTimeout="00:30:00"
receiveTimeout="00:30:00"
sendTimeout="00:30:00">
2. Add the followig before </behaviour>
<serviceTimeouts transactionTimeout="00:30:00" />
3. To increase the CoreService timeout:
In  %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config
and %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config
-  Change all instances of allowExeDefinition from "MachineOnly" to "MachineToApplication"
4. In two files mentioned in previous step, before </configuration> add the section below
<system.transactions>
<defaultSettings timeout="01:30:00"/>
<machineSettings maxTimeout="01:30:00" />
</system.transactions>
5. In %Tridion_HOME%\config\Tridion.ContentManager.config
- Provide a value for transactionTimeout in seconds
<session transactionTimeout="3600" />
```

Thanks everyone